# Logstash log time and date parsing

Tags: regex, logstash-grok

Hello I have below log

```
12-Apr-2021 16:11:41.078 WARNING [https-jsse-nio2-8443-exec-3] org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm.filterLockedAccounts An attempt was made to authenticate the locked user [user1]
```

I am trying to build a pattern for these for logstash.

I have following

```
%{MY_DATE_PATTERN:timestamp}\s%{WORD:severity}\s\[%{DATA:thread}\]\s%{NOTSPACE:type_log}
```

which parses below

```
{
  "timestamp": [
    "12-Apr-2021 16:01:01.505"
  ],
  "severity": [
    "FINE"
  ],
  "thread": [
    "https-jsse-nio2-8443-exec-8"
  ],
  "type_log": [
    "org.apache.catalina.realm.CombinedRealm.authenticate"
  ]
}
```

My Date stamp is a custom pattern it works with grok debugger but not with the system that i am using so i would need help to get date and time with regex. would anyone help me please?

12-Apr-2021 16:11:41.078   GROK REGEX for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `%{MY_DATE_PATTERN:timestamp}`, you can use

```js
(?<timestamp>%{MONTHDAY}-%{MONTH}-%{YEAR} %{HOUR}:%{MINUTE}:%{SECOND})
```

[Legend](https://github.com/hpcugent/logstash-patterns/blob/master/files/grok-patterns):

- `%{MONTHDAY}` - `(?:(?:0[1-9])|(?:[12][0-9])|(?:3[01])|[1-9])`
- `%{MONTH}` - `\b(?:Jan(?:uary|uar)?|Feb(?:ruary|ruar)?|M(?:a|ä)?r(?:ch|z)?|Apr(?:il)?|Ma(?:y|i)?|Jun(?:e|i)?|Jul(?:y)?|Aug(?:ust)?|Sep(?:tember)?|O(?:c|k)?t(?:ober)?|Nov(?:ember)?|De(?:c|z)(?:ember)?)\b`
- `%{YEAR} -` (?>\d\d){1,2}`
- `%{HOUR}` - `(?:2[0123]|[01]?[0-9])`
- `%{MINUTE}` - `(?:[0-5][0-9])`
- `%{SECOND}` - `(?:(?:[0-5]?[0-9]|60)(?:[:.,][0-9]+)?)`.